# How to specify LINQPAD.config file in lprun

Tags: linqpad

I put my `LINQPAD.config` in the same folder as `LINQPad.exe` and it works well for LinqPad GUI.

When I run the same `.linq` program via `lprun.exe`. `lprun.exe` does not use the same `LINQPAD.config` file as `LINQPad.exe` but instead it expects a `LINQPAD.config` file in the same directory as the `.linq` file which is passed as an argument to `lprun.exe`.

This is quite inconvenient. Now, I have two options, either copy `LINQPAD.config` to where my `.linq` script is or copy my `.linq` script to where `lprun.exe` is.

`lprun.exe`'s help doesn't mention anything about specifying a path to `LINQPAD.config`.

Comment: You could try some sort of file symlink between the custom .linq script folder and the main LINQPad.config?  Changing the config location is a [requested feature](https://linqpad.uservoice.com/forums/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/330339-ability-to-add-config) that the LINQPad creator hasn't added support for yet.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I can work out a workaround from there. I am actually fine with a global app.config. Didn't find it limiting for my usual usages. I am just curious of why `LINQPad.exe` and `lprun.exe` uses different `LINQPAD.config` file locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug and will be fixed for the next LINQPad 5 release (5.0.10). It should pick up the config file from the query folder only if it exists, otherwise it should fall back to the lprun.exe folder.